# Error showing an attachment from sub-query in group header

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table people and a table areas. Every person belongs to an area, and every area has a map stored as an attachment field. I am trying to create a report to show the people grouped by area with a map after every group. I also need for every person some data from another table, and I tried using a subquery for that. The problem is that you cannot use a report group with a subquery. I solved that problem by saving the query separately and using

```
SELECT * FROM query1;
```

(where `query1` is my query with a join and subqueries) in my report source. Then I added a group by `area.id` to the report with a footer. In that footer I can show the area name etc. No problem, but if I try to display the map I get a blank map.
I also tried changing my query to

```
SELECT person.name, ..., area.name, area.map, ... FROM query1;
```

It still works without the map, but if I add the attachment control I get an error saying "you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression name".

`query1` looks something like this:

```
SELECT person.*, area.*, 
    (SELECT a FROM b WHERE b.id = person.id AND b.year = Year(Now())),
    (SELECT a FROM b WHERE b.id = person.id AND b.year = Year(Now()) - 1),
    (SELECT a FROM b WHERE b.id = person.id AND b.year = Year(Now()) - 2)
FROM person INNER JOIN area ON person.areaID = area.ID
```

Is there a way to do this in Access?

Comment: What is b.ID field - is this a foreign key for person.ID? Could use better naming. Advise not to use reserved words (name, date, year) as names.

Comment: it actually in b.personId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

1. use Dlookup() to pull value from table b. Expression can be in query or textbox.
   `DLookUp("a","b","ID=" & [Person.ID] & " AND Year=Year(Date())")`
2. build a CROSSTAB query with table b. Join that query to Person table in Query1. Problem with this approach is dynamic nature of column headers in CROSSTAB. There are ways to deal with and it is a common topic.

In both options, reference Query1 directly as report RecordSource or put its SQL statement in report RecordSource - don't use `SELECT * FROM Query1;`

Comment: I used the second option because a `dLookUp` would take much longer (I have ~5000 records)